# python to exe use pyinstaller module comtypes get error

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, comtypes

anyone. When I debugging python the code works very well , but when I made it as an 
EXE file using pyinstaller :

```
pyinstaller test.py
```

when i run the exe file it occurs error is :

> No such file or directory:
>   c:\Db\dist\test\gen\_00020905_0000_0000_C000_000000000046_0_8_4.py

please help